# how to remain in same page when i click on compare button in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, compare

When clicking on the add to compare button, I want to remain on the same page & perform the add function without redirecting to the homepage - is this possible?

Comment: do you mean an ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController::addAction();` This call `_redirectReferer()` which gives redirection url to home page.

You can change this line with `$this->_redirectUrl($product->getProductUrl());`

OR

You can add `referer_url` to `catalog/product_compare/add` request.
`Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare`::`_getUrlParams`

```
protected function _getUrlParams($product)
{
    return array(
        'product' => $product->getId(),
        Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->getEncodedUrl(),
        Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action => $product->getProductUrl(),
    );
}
```